# Extract data from unstructured text file to CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export domain time II windows slave PTP logs to Splunk. The log file is unstructured. I tried using regex extractor of splunk to extract the field but it will be an unreliable solution.

Is there a way to extract the required data in CSV format using PowerShell?

[image: logformat]

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is also possible that someone has written this already. Google would know. Regardless, questions asking for recommendations are off topic on stackoverflow. If you start writing a script and have specific questions about specific problems that you are having with your code then that would be on topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the RegEx that extracts the required data into one or more 'capturing groups', then the results can be exported to CSV quite easily. Something along the lines of:

```
$RegEx = "your regex here"
$FilePath = "path to file"

$PropertySelectors = @( 
    ${n="Field_1";e={$_.Groups[1].Value}},
    ${n="Field_2";e={$_.Groups[2].Value}},
    ${n="Field_3";e={$_.Groups[3].Value}}
    # etc.
    )

select-string -path $filePath -pattern $RegEx -allmatches |
    select-object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
    select-object $PropertySelectors |
    convertto-csv
```